# Different MD5 sums of the same RPM package built twice

Tags: md5, centos6, rpmbuild

I'm building binary RPM package twice from the same batch of files and getting different MD5 sums.

Package is built with `rpmbuild -bb`

What I investigated:

1. I timestamped all files in buildroot with the same date and after packages is built checked timestamps and MD5 sums of files included into RPM with `rpm –q --dump -p my.rpm` command. They are the same in two packages.
2. With `rpm –qpi my.rpm` I found out that package doesn't have signature.

So, what can be the reason of different MD5 sums?

My configuration: CentOS 6, rpm 4.8.0

In older version of `rpm` tool (4.4) there was `-z` option which "freezed time" so hash sum of package remained the same. But now it vanished... Does anybody know if there is substitution for it in newer versions of `rpm`? In man I haven't found info.

Answer (score 1):

There is metadata, such as build time and date, that are always going to change. Unless you mean the files within the RPM have different MD5 signatures.

Comment: In this page I've read about RPM format but haven't found field with build timestamp: [rpm file format](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-file-format-rpm-file-format.html)

Comment: I don't know how old those specs are, but I see "`RPMTAG_BUILDTIME`" as a field, and I know "`rpm -qi`" shows a build timestamp.

Comment: Build time i've made the same with the help of LD_PRELOAD of library that replaces system date functions